# Read from plist instead of Code array: [NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: iphone, search, arrays, plist

I am using tutorial (now inaccessible) "UITableView - Searching table view".

but I really have bad time try to read from plist.

that what I did change:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initialize the array.
    listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    TableViewAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (TableViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    listOfItems = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Countries"];

    //Initialize the copy array.
    copyListOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Set the title
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Countries";

    //Add the search bar
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    searching = NO;
    letUserSelectRow = YES;
}
```

and this how I read plist from My AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
    self.data = tempDict;
    [tempDict release];


    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and this my plist:

```
  <plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Countries</key>
    <array>
        <array>
            <string>USA</string>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>UK</string>
        </array>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe09120'

Comment: In your plist, what is the  <dict/> item doing after the </array> item?

Comment: cant run the plist without <dict>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assigns a newly allocated mutable array to a member.

```
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This leaks the above array and assigns an autoreleased, immutable array to the member.

```
listOfItems = [AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Countries"];
```

Later, when you access listOfItems, it may have been released.  Use this:

```
[listOfItems addObjectsFromArray:[AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Countries"]];
```

This all assumes that `[AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Countries"]` is returning an array.  Given the plist, it should, but it is worth double checking.

Comment: When i Use 
[listOfItems addObjectsFromArray:[AppDelegate.data objectForKey:@"Countries"]];

its run without error but with empty table

Comment: Going by the plist, listOfItems is now an array of arrays.  If you are expecting an array of strings, change the plist.  That sounds like a new question though.

Comment: i have spend 3 days trying to figure it out still cant get it 

all what i need to use this tutorial http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-searching-table-view.html   to read from plist